# LINQ query to create a collection of objects combined from a collection of strings

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is it possible with **single LINQ query** to convert a single dimensional array like this:

```
string[] source = new string[] { "1", "Name1", "Value1", "2", "Name2", "Value2", "3", "Name3", "Value3" };
```

into `IEnumerable<>` of three objects containing three properties, build from each three successive strings?

Comment: If it's possible, I want to see it; gonna be some pretty good looking code.

Comment: For reference, some related questions can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290451/how-to-group-items-by-index-c-sharp-linq and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860305/how-to-use-linq-to-group-every-n-number-of-rows.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, you could group them by the index in the array:

```
string[] source = new string[] { "1", "Name1", "Value1", "2", "Name2", "Value2", "3", "Name3", "Value3" };
var result = source
    .Select((element, index) => new { element, index })
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / 3)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Id = x.ElementAt(0).element,
        Name = x.ElementAt(1).element,
        Value = x.ElementAt(2).element
    }).ToList();

// at this stage the result variable will represent a list of 3 elements where
// each element is an anonymous object containing the 3 properties. You could of course
// replace the anonymous object with a model if you intend to use the result of the query
// outside of the scope of the method it is being executed in.
```

Obviously in this example, there's no error checking. It is something you might consider doing before running the LINQ query. The length of the array should be divisible by 3 obviously.

Comment: "Obviously", it'll go into production as is :)

Comment: Well, I am just mentioning it, because I have seen lots of people doing copy-pasting from SO into their production code (me including) :-)

Comment: Yeah, yeah Darin .. but just look at how beautiful this piece of code is ... this is art.

Comment: That's just brilliant!

Comment: +1 - Because you've answered 20,000 questions!   Several of them my own.